# freeglut_main.c not found in OPTIX 3.8

Tags: opengl, glut, freeglut, optix

I have been working in Optix for my ray tracing project, i went through its classes and function , I know that all the display function and call backs are handled in glutmainloop() and it will never end, my question is I cannot find any function or .c file where glutmainloop() is defined? is it hidden?

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

`glutMainLoop` is a function from the GL Utility Toolkit (GLUT). On Windows the library gets linked in and thus no source code is provided. Precisely it is provided from [the open source freeglut](http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/optix/optix_release_notes.htm):

> GLUT
>
> Most OptiX samples use the GLUT toolkit. Freeglut ships with the Windows OptiX distribution. GLUT is installed by default on Mac OSX. A GLUT installation is required to build samples on Linux.

Take a look at [github's mirror for its code](https://github.com/dcnieho/FreeGLUT/blob/5a6d3b2615d3b4d9629b65b5a0e0539037633963/freeglut/freeglut/src/fg_main.c#L473)

More information here: [opengl glutmainloop()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1862496/1938163)